# Уменьшительная форма от "спаниель": спаниелек или спаниелик?

Tags: уменьшительная-форма, суффиксы-существительных

А фильм, полагаю, как на заказ молодому Тарковскому: он предпочитал, чтобы сценарий ему не мешал. А тут много листвы и воды, **спаниелек**, опять же, молчащий ребёнок, две женские роли (мать и жена), тоже с максимум парой реплик, следовательно, проекции и ретроспеции, - в общем, раздолье для режиссёра. Что получилось у Солодникова, пока никто не знает... Но на постере ребёнок лет пяти, а значит, Казаков отставлен далеко в сторону.

Comment: Я бы выбрал другую форму: _**спаниельчик**_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут, мне кажется, решение зависит от того, речь идет об одном животном или нескольких, а также от того, **к кому именно** относится сочетание "опять же".
Если собачка одна — *спаниел**и**к*, если собак много (как листвы и воды) — *спаниел**е**к* (Р. п., мн. ч. — от *спаниельки*).

При одном животном я бы написала так:
*А тут* [есть, имеются] *много листвы и воды, **спаниелик опять же,** молчащий ребёнок, две женские роли (мать и жена), тоже с максимум парой реплик, следовательно проекции и ретроспе**К**ции, — в общем, раздолье для режиссёра.*

Или так:
*А тут много листвы и воды, **спаниелик, опять же — молчащий ребёнок,** две женские роли (мать и жена), тоже с максимум парой реплик. Следовательно проекции и ретроспекции — в общем, раздолье для режиссёра.*

Comment: Спасибо, Римуль: ВСЁ сделали за меня! )))

Comment: Слово с уменьшительным значением не вписывается в грамматику языка: безударный ЕК  нехарактерен для слов м. рода на мягкий согласный (сравнить соболь – соболёк), а форма ж.р. спаниелька не используется. Поэтому  приходится использовать  начльную разговорную/сниженную  форму спаниелик, которой нет в словаре.  Сравнить: стол – столик. За образец можно взять слово "телик": Русский орфографический словарь:
телик, -а (телевизор; сниж.).  Не телек.

Comment: Форма женского рода очень даже используется. *Собачка спаниелька.* (• https://xn--80agbgejzraimpn9lqb.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0/; • https://www.livemaster.ru/item/37526722-kukly-i-igrushki-spanielka; • https://m.vk.com/product-39189505_4169113; • https://www.lavka-podarkov.ru/catalog/new_year_presents/skulpturi/47401/) А словарями не зафиксирована ни одна, ни другая форма.

Answer (score 2):

У спаниеля  не может быть формы спаниелек.

Cпаниель - спаниел-ик (уменьшительный суффикс -ик).

Cпаниелик - спаниелики (им. мн. ч) - спаниеликов (род. мн. ч.); (ср. столик - столики - столиков).

Cпаниелек будет, но только если исходная форма - *спаниелька*, то есть 1 склонение женского рода.

Спаниелька - спаниельки - спаниелек; (ср. панелька - панельки - панелек).

Для существительных 2 скл. с исходом на -л (-ль) актуален уменьшительный суффикс -ик:  стол - столик, вал - валик, карнавал - карнавалик (не карнавалек же!), кинжал - кинжалик (не кинжалек).

Дайте пример сущ. 2 склонения с исходом на -л, у которого была бы уменьшительная форма на -ок, -ек, -ёк (вроде гриб - грибок, зять - зятёк, муж - муж-енёк и т. д.).